# Unexpected jump in page scroll position on adding content to page [infinite scroll] [mobile browsers only]

Tags: javascript, html, css, infinite-scroll

I'm developing a photo gallery app with infinite scroll - photos are loaded in batches as the user scrolls to the bottom of the page.

When the newly-retrieved photos are added to the page, the scroll position "jumps" up by a few hundred pixels.

[Here's a video recording](https://www.loom.com/share/995dd9cd93ad4a3a88fb907e22f03b9a?sid=a6eb3e8b-9114-4c65-8b68-20f7b00c9722) of the issue (jump happens at 8s).

---

What I've been able to figure out so far:

1. The jump **only** happens on mobile firefox/chrome, and in responsive mode on desktop firefox/chrome.

   - It does not happen when viewing the page the usual way (i.e. without responsive mode enabled) in desktop firefox/chrome.
2. The jump is not due to a [layout shift](https://web.dev/cls/#measure-layout-shifts-in-javascript). The positions of the existing photos are the same throughout.
3. The jump is (probably?) unrelated to [scroll anchoring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-anchor/Guide_to_scroll_anchoring). It happens whether scroll-anchoring is enabled or disabled.
4. The jump happens when the user is "close-enough" to the bottom of the page. This "close-enough-to-cause-page-jump" threshold seem to be dependent exclusively on the height of the viewport, and is always approximately `100vh - 100px`.
5. The amount by which the page jumps causes the user to always be x pixels from what the page bottom would have been, had additional content not been added to the page. Also x is always exactly equal to the "close-enough-to-cause-page-jump" threshold.

Any information that could help me track down the cause of this vexatious behavior would be very helpful.